# Как изменять строчку таблицы при выборе параметра select

Tags: javascript

Не могу найти подходящее решение   есть таблица нужно чтоб при выборе количества часов изменялась строчка в таблице, попробовал один вариант но он не работает
Может кто поможет решить данную задачу, по факту ничего сложного но не могу ничего сделать..
есть таблица Норма тривалості робочого часу в годинах за: с 10 строками, и нужно чтоб в выпадающем списке выберать и показивалась только одна строка чтоб человек не путался в цыфрах а видел только ему нужную строку

```
var $dependerItem = $('.40god');
$('#edit-field-sity-tid').change(function() {
var curentSelectedVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
if (curentSelectedVal == 40) {
$dependerItem.removeClass('hide');
} else {
$dependerItem.addClass('hide');
}
});

<table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="10" class="40god " align="left"
height="17">Тривалість робочого часу
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38.5">38,5</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
</select>
<br>
</td>
<td align="center">151</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">152</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">2003</td>
</tr>
<tr class="39god hide">
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">1957,8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="38,5god hide">
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">1932,7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Не много не понятен вопрос. Для чего все это? Где и как хочешь это использовать?

Comment: Что именно должно изменяться в строчке таблицы при выборе часов?

Comment: есть таблица Норма тривалості робочого часу в годинах за: с 10 строками, и нужно чтоб в выпадающем списке выберать и показивалась только одна строка чтоб человек не путался в цыфрах а видел только ему нужную строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фух... скопировал занново данное решение, плюс добавил класс для строки и всё прекрасно работает, и не конфликтует с остальным текстом на странице...
Спасибо, ihhaman

```js
$(document).on('change','.edit-field-sity-tid',function(){ 
  changed($(this)); 
});

function changed(item)
{ 
 var selected = item.val();  
  $("table tr.real").addClass('hide');
  var selector = "table tr."+selected+"god";  
  $(selector).removeClass('hide');
  $(".edit-field-sity-tid").val(selected);
}
```

```css
.hide
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="40god real">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="37">37</option>

</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу</td>
<td align="center">151</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">152</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">2003</td>
</tr>
<tr class="39god hide real">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="37">37</option>

</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу </td>
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">1957,8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="38god hide real">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="37">37</option>

</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу </td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">1932,7</td>
</tr>
<tr class="37god hide real">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="37">37</option>

</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу </td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">1932,7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю поменять разметку и js-код на следующие.
Выбираем год, скрываем все строки, класс которых не соответствует выбранному.

```js
$(document).on('change','.edit-field-sity-tid',function(){ 
  changed($(this)); 
});

function changed(item)
{ 
 var selected = item.val();  
  $("table tr").addClass('hide');
  var selector = "table tr."+selected+"god";  
  $(selector).removeClass('hide');
  $(".edit-field-sity-tid").val(selected);
}
```

```css
.hide
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="40god ">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу</td>
<td align="center">151</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">152</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">168</td>
<td align="center">175</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">159</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">176</td>
<td align="center">2003</td>
</tr>
<tr class="39god hide">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу </td>
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">148,2</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">163,8</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">156</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">171,6</td>
<td align="center">1957,8</td>
</tr>
<tr class="38god hide">
<td align="left">
<select class="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid"
class="form-select">
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
</select>
<br/>
Тривалість робочого часу </td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">146,3</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">161,7</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">154</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">169,4</td>
<td align="center">1932,7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, отличное робочее решение, только при выборе из списка код прячем все таблицы на странице и остаётся только одна строка..
Можно ли как то ограничить смену класса hide ?

Comment: Конечно можно. В селекторах нужно указать, например, конкретную таблицу c id="table_id": $("table#table_id tr").addClass('hide');
  var selector = "table#table_id tr."+selected+"god";  
  $(selector).removeClass('hide'); Или если нужно управлять частью строк в таблице, то добавить этим строкам некий класс и работать уже с ним.

Comment: а как в данной строчке указать чтоб изменяло класс на хайд
$("table#table_id tr").addClass('hide');
только в строках с класом "+selected+"god" кроме выбраного селектора?